# get multiple string outputs from stored procedure using entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, model-view-controller

The following stored procedure displays three strings and a table row result as output.
Is there any way we can display all the results on a mvc view output panel using entity framework?

I could see the first string result in the code below. But is there anyway to get the other two select string outputs and
the table row result.

```
private CustomerEntities db = new CustomerEntities();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var results = db.usp_CustomerData("124544", 1500);
            var abc = results.ToList();
            return View();
        }

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_CustomerData]
@CustomerID varchar(6),
@MinsBack int
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Count int
    SET @Count = (SELECT Count(*)
                    FROM Customer WITH (NOLOCK)
                    WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID AND                       
                          DATEDIFF(mi, ReceivedAt, GETUTCDATE()) < @MinsBack)
    IF (@Count = 1)
        SELECT 'Ok:  1 message in Customer table'
    ELSE
        SELECT 'ERROR:  Expected 1 message in Customer table, but found ' + CONVERT(varchar(3), @Count) + ' messages.'


    SET @Count = (SELECT Count(*)
                    FROM CustomerDetails WITH (NOLOCK)
                    WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID AND
                          DATEDIFF(mi, LastUpdatedAt, GETDATE()) < @MinsBack)
    IF (@Count = 1)
        SELECT 'Ok:  1 record in CustomerDetails table'
    ELSE
        SELECT 'ERROR:  Expected 1 record in CustomerDetails table, but found ' + CONVERT(varchar(3), @Count) + ' records.'


    SET @Count = (SELECT Count(*)
                    FROM CustomerProduct WITH (NOLOCK)
                    WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID AND
                          DATEDIFF(mi, LastUpdatedAt, GETDATE()) < @MinsBack)
    IF (@Count = 1)
        SELECT 'Ok:  1 record in CustomerProduct table'
    ELSE
        SELECT 'ERROR:  Expected 1 record in CustomerProduct table, but found ' + CONVERT(varchar(3), @Count) + ' records.'

    SELECT *FROM Customer where customerID = @CustomerID

END
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggestion you could create a temporary table in your SQL script which will be used as temporary store.

```
CREATE TABLE #Results
(
    Message VARCHAR(512)
)
```

Instead of a direct `SELECT` in each `IF` or `ELSE` you should insert the string into the temp table.
At the end you could reach your goal to get all inserted strings to return them by:

```
SELECT * FROM #Results
```

To get customers - like you do at the end - you should trigger a new query to database.

Depending on your case you should consider to querying the database by data context instead of querying the database by store procedures.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something as suggest in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj691402(v=vs.113).aspx) but I summarized below

For each results set you will need to do a reader.NextResult();

```
var someReturnObject = new ResultObject();

using (var context = new LinqPadDbContext(@"Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=StackOverflow;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
{
    var cmd = context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[GetSomeData]";

    try
    {           
        context.Database.Connection.Open();

        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        var result1 = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.Translate<string>(reader);

        someResultObject.Text1 = result1.First();

        //for each extra result, start here
        reader.NextResult();

        var users = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.Translate<User>(reader);

        someResultObject.Users = users.Select(x => x);
        //stop here
    }
    finally
    {
        context.Database.Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Combined with the other answer only two outputs have to be dealt with.